# How to check if child exists

Tags: jquery

I have a div which could potentially have a hyperlink with an id of reply. How can I check if that `a[id=reply]` exists? I thought it might be something like this but it alerts the message even if that hyperlink does not exist.

```
if($('div[chunk_id='+reply_chunk_id+']').children('a[id=reply]')){              
    alert('test');
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Check the [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) of the selector to see how many elements it matched, in this case:

```
if($("#reply").length) {
  //child exists
}
```

However, it *sounds* like you have multiple elements with `id="reply"`, which is invalid.  Instead use `class="reply"` and your selector will look like this:

```
if($("div[chunk_id='"+reply_chunk_id+"'] > a.reply").length){  
  //child exists
}
```

Comment: @Scarface - You should use a class instead...an ID should appear only once per page.

Comment: Use `"+reply_chunk_id+"` instead of `'+reply_chunk_id+'`, otherwise it sees it as a value, not a variable.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do it :

```
if($("div[chunk_id="+reply_chunk_id+"]").children('.reply').length > 0){
    // it exists
}
```

Comment: Here we search for **any** child of class `.reply`, just like the OP asked, not only first-level children as in the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

`:has` is also the other option along with length, for example if you want to get only those tr which has td in it

```
if($('tr:has(td)')) {}
```